# :has Selector in CSS doesn't allow specificity

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

When using the css selector `:has`
I'm only allowed to put basic properties such as tag name:

```
.field:has(input)
```

But not:

```
.field:has(input[type="checkbox"])
```

Why is this? I want to select the element of class **field**, NOT the input.

Comment: You mean **JQuery** `:has` selector? [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/has/)

Comment: @JoshC agree, that would be more logical.

Comment: @Vucko No, but it is the same concept, it's a CSS pseudo-class.

Comment: @JoshC I definitely do NOT mean :not, that's the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Does this selector exists?

Comment: I don't think `:has()` is a css pseudo, just jQuery. See [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes). Can you provide documentation showing otherwise?

Comment: You cannot select a parent element using CSS only. See JoshC's answer for a jQuery solution.

Comment: It's most definitely not a CSS selector, I'm not sure where you got the impression that it was. If you want to talk about specificity, an invalid selector doesn't count at all since it can't possibly match, but I don't think that was what you meant when you said "specificity". The rule you mentioned about only allowing simple selectors only applies to `:not()` and is not something inherent to all functional pseudo-classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:has` isn't a selector in CSS - you are talking about jQuery.

Use: `$('.field:has(input[type="checkbox"])');`

[**Working jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnC43/)

Comment: Ok, what I really mean then, is how do you do this with pure css?

Comment: @FengHuo You can't - this is your only option.

Answer (score 0):

```
.field input[type="checkbox"]
```

Maybe like this?

Comment: I want to select the element with class field. Not the element's child of type input. I just want to select only the fields that HAVE an input of type "checkbox".